# why is my python script not shown as a process, even though its running?

Tags: python, process, visibility, malware, taskmanager

I wrote a python script that calls another executable every 5 seconds.
And while its working fine and does what its supposed to do, its not shown
as a process at taskmanager(its shown on process monitor tho).
The script is called "böse", the called exe is called "hey", and the hey.exe
is shown as a process, while böse.exe is not.
Using pyinstaller i converted both of them to executables with
"pyinstaller -F -w filename.py"

Code is runned on VM with windows 10.

```
#böse
import time
import subprocess

i = 1
while i == 1:
     subprocess.call(r"Path/to/file/hey")
     time.sleep(5)
```

```
#hey
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text = "Hey brudi")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

A bit background info: I currently have to write a little paper about malware persistence techniques for university so i wanted to start with writing a executable which "comes back" after closing it.
This is just meant as a idiomatic way to get in touch with the topic before actually diving into the common techniques used by actual malware authors.
Which is why i would like to understand why the böse.exe isnt shown in taskmanager.
Hope you guys can help me :)

PS: This is my first post here, hope i've done it the right way lol

Answer (score 0):

The second script creates a process with a visible GUI main window (`root.mainloop()` triggers showing a Tkinter root window) so it is shown in your task manager. The first process has no any visible window attached to it.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! So this means every process that has not an visible window is not shown in taskmanager?

Comment: Yes. Iirc the point is in having that *main application window* attached to process as processes showing only pop-ups also don't show up there.